# scala spark - groupBy to find mean between months in a date range

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am looking at this drone rental dataset.
I would like to try grouping by the Result column in Spark to show the mean result ($) each drone made as a function of the days it spent in that month.

ie. the value in the Result column divided by total days then attributed to the days in each month between the start and end dates

```
+------+------------------+------------------+--------+
| Drone|     Start        |      End         | Result |
+------+------------------+------------------+--------+
| DR1    16/06/2013 10:30   22/08/2013 07:00    2786  |
| DR1    20/04/2013 23:30   16/06/2013 10:30    7126  |
| DR1    24/01/2013 23:00   20/04/2013 23:30    2964  |
| DR2    01/03/2014 19:00   07/05/2014 18:00    8884  |
| DR2    04/09/2015 09:00   04/11/2015 07:00    7828  |
| DR2    04/10/2013 05:00   24/12/2013 07:00    5700  |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

This is difficult as it is a longer-term rental business and not values associated with one date and so a simple groupBy isn't working for me.

kindly please note the drone is hired on a per minute basis in the full dataset is a little more messy.

I would appreciate some help on the correct thought process for approaching a problem like this and what the code would look like.

How would you change what I have written below to consider each month as a separate case? (I only can base it on the start date) :/

```
val df_avgs = df.groupBy("Start").mean()
df_avgs.select($"Date",$"avg(Result)").show()
```

taking the first example from each drone type, my expected output would be:

```
+------+-------+-------+---------+
|Drone | Month | Days  |   Avg   |
+------+-------+-------+---------+
|DR1     June      X       $YY   |
|DR1     July      X       $YY   |
|DR1     August    X       $YY   |
|DR2     March     Y       $ZZ   |
|DR2     April     Y       $ZZ   |
|DR2     May       Y       $ZZ   |
+--------------------------------+
```

**Thanks so much**

Comment: Will the result value be unique across all drones ?

Comment: If you only had first two lines of your table in database, what exact output would you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please check this out?. I have used "MMM-yy" in the date-formatting so that if the start and end date spans across years, then it will distinguish easily. You could change that to "MMM" if you just need the month alone.

```
scala> val df_t = Seq(("DR1","16/06/2013 10:30","22/08/2013 07:00",2786),("DR1","20/04/2013 23:30","16/06/2013 10:30",7126),("DR1","24/01/2013 23:00","20/04/2013 23:30",2964),("DR2","01/03/2014 19:00","07/05/2014 18:00",8884),("DR2","04/09/2015 09:00","04/11/2015 07:00",7828),("DR2","04/10/2013 05:00","24/12/2013 07:00",5700)).toDF("drone","start","end","result")
df_t: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [drone: string, start: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> val df = df_t.withColumn("start",to_timestamp('start,"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")).withColumn("end",to_timestamp('end,"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"))
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [drone: string, start: timestamp ... 2 more fields]

scala> df.show(false)
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+------+
|drone|start              |end                |result|
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+------+
|DR1  |2013-06-16 10:30:00|2013-08-22 07:00:00|2786  |
|DR1  |2013-04-20 23:30:00|2013-06-16 10:30:00|7126  |
|DR1  |2013-01-24 23:00:00|2013-04-20 23:30:00|2964  |
|DR2  |2014-03-01 19:00:00|2014-05-07 18:00:00|8884  |
|DR2  |2015-09-04 09:00:00|2015-11-04 07:00:00|7828  |
|DR2  |2013-10-04 05:00:00|2013-12-24 07:00:00|5700  |
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+------+


scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def months_range(a:java.sql.Date,b:java.sql.Date):Seq[String]=
{
import java.time._
import java.time.format._
val start = a.toLocalDate
val end = b.toLocalDate
(start.toEpochDay until end.toEpochDay).map(LocalDate.ofEpochDay(_)).map(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM-yy").format(_)).toSet.toSeq
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

months_range: (a: java.sql.Date, b: java.sql.Date)Seq[String]

scala> val udf_months_range = udf(  months_range(_:java.sql.Date,_:java.sql.Date):Seq[String] )
udf_months_range: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function2>,ArrayType(StringType,true),Some(List(DateType, DateType)))

scala> val df2 = df.withColumn("days",datediff('end,'start)).withColumn("diff_months",udf_months_range('start,'end))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [drone: string, start: timestamp ... 4 more fields]

scala> df2.show(false)
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+------+----+--------------------------------+
|drone|start              |end                |result|days|diff_months                     |
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+------+----+--------------------------------+
|DR1  |2013-06-16 10:30:00|2013-08-22 07:00:00|2786  |67  |[Jun-13, Jul-13, Aug-13]        |
|DR1  |2013-04-20 23:30:00|2013-06-16 10:30:00|7126  |57  |[Apr-13, May-13, Jun-13]        |
|DR1  |2013-01-24 23:00:00|2013-04-20 23:30:00|2964  |86  |[Jan-13, Feb-13, Mar-13, Apr-13]|
|DR2  |2014-03-01 19:00:00|2014-05-07 18:00:00|8884  |67  |[Mar-14, Apr-14, May-14]        |
|DR2  |2015-09-04 09:00:00|2015-11-04 07:00:00|7828  |61  |[Sep-15, Oct-15, Nov-15]        |
|DR2  |2013-10-04 05:00:00|2013-12-24 07:00:00|5700  |81  |[Oct-13, Nov-13, Dec-13]        |
+-----+-------------------+-------------------+------+----+--------------------------------+


scala> df2.withColumn("month",explode('diff_months)).withColumn("Avg",'result/'days).select("drone","month","days","avg").show(false)
+-----+------+----+------------------+
|drone|month |days|avg               |
+-----+------+----+------------------+
|DR1  |Jun-13|67  |41.582089552238806|
|DR1  |Jul-13|67  |41.582089552238806|
|DR1  |Aug-13|67  |41.582089552238806|
|DR1  |Apr-13|57  |125.01754385964912|
|DR1  |May-13|57  |125.01754385964912|
|DR1  |Jun-13|57  |125.01754385964912|
|DR1  |Jan-13|86  |34.46511627906977 |
|DR1  |Feb-13|86  |34.46511627906977 |
|DR1  |Mar-13|86  |34.46511627906977 |
|DR1  |Apr-13|86  |34.46511627906977 |
|DR2  |Mar-14|67  |132.59701492537314|
|DR2  |Apr-14|67  |132.59701492537314|
|DR2  |May-14|67  |132.59701492537314|
|DR2  |Sep-15|61  |128.327868852459  |
|DR2  |Oct-15|61  |128.327868852459  |
|DR2  |Nov-15|61  |128.327868852459  |
|DR2  |Oct-13|81  |70.37037037037037 |
|DR2  |Nov-13|81  |70.37037037037037 |
|DR2  |Dec-13|81  |70.37037037037037 |
+-----+------+----+------------------+


scala>
```

**EDIT1**

Splitting on based on the number of days in each month. The code has to be changed from UDF.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def months_range(a:java.sql.Date,b:java.sql.Date)=
{
import java.time._
import java.time.format._
val start = a.toLocalDate
val end = b.toLocalDate
(start.toEpochDay until end.toEpochDay).map(LocalDate.ofEpochDay(_)).map(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM-yy").format(_)).groupBy(identity).map( x => (x._1,x._2.length) )
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

months_range: (a: java.sql.Date, b: java.sql.Date)scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]

scala> val udf_months_range = udf(  months_range(_:java.sql.Date,_:java.sql.Date):Map[String,Int] )
udf_months_range: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function2>,MapType(StringType,IntegerType,false),Some(List(DateType, DateType)))

scala>  val df2 = df.withColumn("days",datediff('end,'start)).withColumn("diff_months",udf_months_range('start,'end))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [drone: string, start: timestamp ... 4 more fields]

scala> val df3=df2.select(col("*"),explode('diff_months).as(Seq("month","month_days")) ).withColumn("mnth_rent",'result*('month_days/'days)).select("drone","month","month_days","days","mnth_rent")
df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [drone: string, month: string ... 3 more fields]

scala> df3.show(false)
+-----+------+----------+----+------------------+
|drone|month |month_days|days|mnth_rent         |
+-----+------+----------+----+------------------+
|DR1  |Aug-13|21        |67  |873.223880597015  |
|DR1  |Jul-13|31        |67  |1289.044776119403 |
|DR1  |Jun-13|15        |67  |623.7313432835821 |
|DR1  |May-13|31        |57  |3875.543859649123 |
|DR1  |Apr-13|11        |57  |1375.1929824561403|
|DR1  |Jun-13|15        |57  |1875.2631578947367|
|DR1  |Apr-13|19        |86  |654.8372093023256 |
|DR1  |Feb-13|28        |86  |965.0232558139536 |
|DR1  |Mar-13|31        |86  |1068.4186046511627|
|DR1  |Jan-13|8         |86  |275.72093023255815|
|DR2  |Apr-14|30        |67  |3977.910447761194 |
|DR2  |Mar-14|31        |67  |4110.507462686567 |
|DR2  |May-14|6         |67  |795.5820895522388 |
|DR2  |Nov-15|3         |61  |384.983606557377  |
|DR2  |Oct-15|31        |61  |3978.1639344262294|
|DR2  |Sep-15|27        |61  |3464.8524590163934|
|DR2  |Nov-13|30        |81  |2111.111111111111 |
|DR2  |Oct-13|28        |81  |1970.3703703703702|
|DR2  |Dec-13|23        |81  |1618.5185185185185|
+-----+------+----------+----+------------------+


scala> df3.groupBy('drone,'month).agg(sum('month_days).as("s_month_days"),sum('mnth_rent).as("mnth_rent"),max('days).as("days")).orderBy('drone,'month).show(false)
+-----+------+------------+------------------+----+
|drone|month |s_month_days|mnth_rent         |days|
+-----+------+------------+------------------+----+
|DR1  |Apr-13|30          |2030.030191758466 |86  |
|DR1  |Aug-13|21          |873.223880597015  |67  |
|DR1  |Feb-13|28          |965.0232558139536 |86  |
|DR1  |Jan-13|8           |275.72093023255815|86  |
|DR1  |Jul-13|31          |1289.044776119403 |67  |
|DR1  |Jun-13|30          |2498.994501178319 |67  |
|DR1  |Mar-13|31          |1068.4186046511627|86  |
|DR1  |May-13|31          |3875.543859649123 |57  |
|DR2  |Apr-14|30          |3977.910447761194 |67  |
|DR2  |Dec-13|23          |1618.5185185185185|81  |
|DR2  |Mar-14|31          |4110.507462686567 |67  |
|DR2  |May-14|6           |795.5820895522388 |67  |
|DR2  |Nov-13|30          |2111.111111111111 |81  |
|DR2  |Nov-15|3           |384.983606557377  |61  |
|DR2  |Oct-13|28          |1970.3703703703702|81  |
|DR2  |Oct-15|31          |3978.1639344262294|61  |
|DR2  |Sep-15|27          |3464.8524590163934|61  |
+-----+------+------------+------------------+----+


scala>
```

Comment: oh my god this is amazing! I have so much to learn, thank you for inspiring

Comment: glad that it helped you...yes spark is really interesting.. keep learning

Comment: Hi - I noticed something off with the dates and I hope you can help. Based on my numbers drone 1 is doing 14.562 days in June and 31 days in July. However, your output is always the same number of days? Thanks

Comment: I guessed the calculation and worked it out.. could you please update the X, YY in your question and how to arrive at 14.5625

Comment: Yeah my explanation might have been lacking. I worked it out in Python but if I was to provide an example.. if the drone is rented between 24/01/2018 and 20/04/2018 then it would been rented for 7 days in January, 28 days in February, 31 days in March and 20 days in April

Comment: for the first record, I get (15/67)*41.58 = 9.3 only.. how do you get 14.56 ?.. please let me know and I can work it out

Comment: please check my EDIT1